# Cannot deploy artifact to Nexus repository ,status: 401 Unauthorized

Tags: java, maven, nexus, artifacts, build-tools

I have checked forums and I see that this question was asked before but a very long time ago.

I have a basic application and I am able to create artifacts with **mvn package** command.

```
[INFO] --- spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.3.5.RELEASE:repackage (default) @ java-maven-app ---
[INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  1.324 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-05-10T11:03:24+02:00
```

Then I am trying to deploy it to remote Nexus Repo via **mvn deploy** command ,then I am facing with following error.

```
Failed to retrieve remote metadata com.example:java-maven-app:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: Could not transfer metadata com.example:java-maven-app:1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to nexus-snapshots (http://167.71.41.177:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/): authentication failed for http://167.71.41.177:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/com/example/java-maven-app/1.1.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, status: 401 Unauthorized -> [Help 1]
```

I am able to login to Nexus repo with this user without any issue and I have following settings.xml in my mac.

```
<servers>
  <server>
    <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
    <username>nexus</username>
    <password>Krakow123</password>
  </server>
</servers>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>java-maven-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.8.2</version>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>

        <plugins>
            <!-- to handle any Java version mismatch, add the following configuration for maven-compiler-plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.occurrent/subscription-api-blocking -->
    <distributionManagement>
        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>nexus-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://167.71.41.177:8081/repository/maven-snapshots/</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0-alpha.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-databind -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.occurrent</groupId>
            <artifactId>subscription-api-blocking</artifactId>
            <version>0.14.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testcontainers/elasticsearch -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>1.17.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>7.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

and I have following snippet from pom.xml ,everything should be fine actually ,anybody can help ?

Comment: You pom file contains a mix of different releases of spring boot: `2.3.5.RELEASE` .. `2.6.7`. I would strongly recommend to first cleanup your issues in your pom file..

Comment: Are you using a proxy or alike which accessing via Browser? Because from command line it could be different or OAuth2 or a like?

Comment: thanks ,agree ,I have removed 2.3.5 and updated pom.xml

I do not have any proxy